# How to add inner array to JSON object for saving to Mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

```
$scope.createProduct = function () {
        console.log("inside createProduct click")
        console.log($scope.Product);
        console.log($scope.selectedGroups);
        $http.post('Product/CreateProduct', $scope.Product).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.success);
            if (response.success == true) {
                $scope.status = "Successfully Created Product";
                $mdDialog.hide();
            }
        });
    };
```

Above is my posting code. I want to add `"$scope.selectedGroups"` to `$scope.Product`

For Eg:

```
$scope.Product = { 
    "ProductName": "FirstProduct",
    "ContentLink:  "SampleLink"
    "SelectedGroups":{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}
}
```

Here `"SelectedGroups"= $scope.selectedGroups`

How to append this from controller

Comment: I might be missing something but it sounds like it should be as simple as (?): $scope.Product.SelectedGroups = $scope.selectedGroups